# Why can't users see library items that were created prior to them being given access permissions?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-library

I am new to SharePoint and need a bit of help.
We are currently using SharePoint 2007, Moss 2007 etc.

My question is this:  Why can't users see library items that were created prior to them being given access permissions?
The users have been given "Full Control" over the library in question yet can't see anything.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2):

Perform below checklist:

1. Is Permission inheritance broken at item level?
2. Is default view has some filters applied to it which is returning no documents for current user?
3. Is documents checked out?

Comment: as suggested above.. this is happening because Items are having different permission than the list.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the access may not be inherited to item level. Please check whether the library is maintaining item level permission.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (it is rather a comment) as per StackExchange standards. Check [answer].